# Javafx SceneBuilder Table getter Methode is giving me an NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

As described in title...

```
@FXML
private TableView<Product> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> iname;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> ilast;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Product, String> iid;

public ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
   new Product("John", "Smith", "23")
);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

       iname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("name")); 
       ilast.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("lastname"));
       iid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("id"));
       table.setItems(data);
    }

public void addItems(String name, String lastname, String id) {
    Product p = new Product(name, hwid, core, os, proc);
    data.add(p);
    getTable().refresh();
}

public TableView<Product> getTable() {
    return table;
}
```

table.setItems(data);

Is working fine, but if I am trying to refresh the table by the getter methode, I am getting an NullPointerException.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: How do you invoke `getTable` (or `addItems`)? I guess a instance of the controller not used with the fxml is used...

Comment: MainController m = new MainController();
           Product e = new Product("John", "Smith", "21");
           m.data.add(e);
           m.addItems("John", "Smith", "213");

Comment: And here is the Error:

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.MainController.addItems(MainController.java:65)
 at me.jan.utils.ThreadServer.run(ThreadServer.java:33)

Comment: m.addItems will be opened in a Thread